# Обособление в предложении со словом "предположительно"

Tags: пунктуация

Какой вариант пунктуации правильный?

1. Ингибирование ... приводит к снижению секреции
   внутриглазной **жидкости, предположительно** за счет уменьшения образования гидрокарбонат-ионов.
2. Ингибирование ... приводит к снижению секреции
   внутриглазной **жидкости, предположительно,** за счет уменьшения образования гидрокарбонат-ионов.
3. Ингибирование ... приводит к снижению секреции
   внутриглазной жидкости **предположительно** за счет уменьшения образования гидрокарбонат-ионов.

Скорее всего, здесь "предположительно" не вводное слово, а первый и третий вариант - оба правильные, но я не уверена.

Comment: Приведённый контекст недостаточен для принятия решения.

Comment: Предложение целиком: Ингибирование карбоангидразы цилиарного тела приводит к снижению секреции внутриглазной жидкости, предположительно за счет уменьшения образования гидрокарбонат-ионов, что, в свою очередь, приводит к замедлению транспорта натрия и жидкости.

Comment: Keyti, подскажите, с какой частью предложения должны быть связаны слова "что, в свою очередь..."  Т. е. какой из этих вариантов правилен: 1) _ингибирование карбоангидразы... приводит к замедлению транспорта натрия_ или же 2) _уменьшение образования гидрокарбонат-ионов... приводит к замедлению транспорта натрия_? П

Comment: slava1947, к сожалению, не уверена на 100%, т. к. я не автор текста, а из контекста совершенно непонятно: предложение стоит особняком, а я не специалист в этой теме. Но, по-моему, второй вариант правильный.

Comment: Я тоже не специалист но логичен только второй вариант: меньше гидрокарбонат-ионов -> меньше натрия и жидкости транспортируется -> снижается секреция внутриглазной жидкости

Answer (score 1):

Запятая после слова "жидкости" требуется, так как далее идет уточнение, которое нужно выделять запятыми.

Как указал @slava1947, "предположительно" - вводное слово, но, по моему мнению, после него запятая не нужна в соответствии со следующим правилом:

*Если вводное слово стоит в начале обособленного оборота – запятые ставятся перед вводным словом и после всего обособленного оборота. После вводного слова запятая не ставится (иначе говоря, запятая, которая должна была «закрывать» вводное слово, переносится в конец обособленного оборота).* [[ПУНКТУАЦИЯ ПРИ ВВОДНЫХ СЛОВАХ И СОЧЕТАНИЯХ](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach2)]

Пример: 
В результате кусок штукатурки, предположительно весом более 10 килограммов, повредил бампер припаркованного автомобиля. ([Грамота](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=272124))

Comment: _М_Г: А "предположительно" - не вводное слово, после него запятая не нужна._ === По-моему, в приведённом Вами предложении с Грамоты.ру запятой после _предположительно_ нет не потому, что оно "не вводное", а потому, что это вводное относится к обороту, выделенному запятыми.

Comment: @slava1947 Вы правы, сответствует правилу: Если вводное слово стоит в начале обособленного оборота – запятые ставятся перед вводным словом и после всего обособленного оборота. После вводного слова запятая не ставится (иначе говоря, запятая, которая должна была «закрывать» вводное слово, переносится в конец обособленного оборота). (http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach2)

Answer (score 0):

> Ингибирование карбоангидразы цилиарного тела приводит к снижению
>   секреции внутриглазной жидкости, предположительно за счет уменьшения
>   образования гидрокарбонат-ионов, что, в свою очередь, приводит к
>   замедлению транспорта натрия и жидкости.

В зависимости от контекста и от того, с какой частью предложения связаны слова *"что, в свою очередь, приводит к замедлению транспорта натрия и жидкости"*, возможны, на мой взгляд,  такие варианты:

*1) Ингибирование карбоангидразы цилиарного тела **приводит к снижению секреции** внутриглазной жидкости (предположительно, за счет уменьшения образования гидрокарбонат-ионов), **что, в свою очередь, приводит** к замедлению транспорта натрия и жидкости.*

*2) Ингибирование карбоангидразы цилиарного тела приводит к снижению секреции внутриглазной жидкости —  предположительно, **за счет уменьшения образования гидрокарбонат-ионов, приводящего, в свою очередь,**  к замедлению транспорта натрия и жидкости.*

*3) Ингибирование карбоангидразы цилиарного тела приводит к снижению секреции внутриглазной жидкости за счет, **предположительно**, уменьшения образования гидрокарбонат-ионов, приводящего, в свою очередь,  к замедлению транспорта натрия и жидкости.*

Comment: По-моему, логичен только такой вариант: меньше гидрокарбонат-ионов -> меньше натрия и жидкости транспортируется -> снижается секреция внутриглазной жидкости. Поэтому слово "приводящего" вносит необходимую ясность. Но почему стоит запятая после "предположительно" (в отличие от примера, приведенного Грамотой)?

Comment: Я имею в виду ваш третий вариант.

Comment: _М_Г: Но почему стоит запятая после "предположительно" (в отличие от примера, приведенного Грамотой)? Я имею в виду ваш третий вариант._ ===  

Так в третьем-то варианте обособленного оборота нет. См.: _То-то и то-то приводит к снижению секреции внутриглазной жидкости за счет уменьшения образования гидрокарбонат-ионов…_

Comment: Я понимаю так: без "предположительно" - нет оборота, но верните  "предположительно" - вся конструкция становится уточнением. Аналогично с предложением с сайта Грамота: "Кусок штукатурки весом более 10 килограммов повредил бампер." (нет оборота) и "Кусок штукатурки, предположительно весом более 10 килограммов, повредил бампер." (есть оборот)

Comment: Но: "Кусок штукатурки весом, предположительно, более 10 килограммов повредил бампер." (нет оборота)

Comment: _М_Г: Я понимаю так: без "предположительно" - нет оборота, но верните "предположительно" - вся конструкция становится уточнением._ ===  Хорошо, верну. Поставлю его при этом (для простоты понимания) в другое место: 

_То-то и то-то приводит к снижению секреции внутриглазной жидкости за счет, предположительно, уменьшения образования гидрокарбонат-ионов…_

Comment: С этом согласен, но оттенки смысла разные. (Вариант 1) Главное, что первое приводит ко второму, а остальное лишь догадка - выделяем ее как обособленный оборот. (Вариант 2) Нам важно знать, почему первое приводит ко второму, тогда пишем: "..за счет, предположительно, третьего", как у вас.

Comment: _М_Г: С этом согласен, но оттенки смысла разные._ === Конечно разные. А какой смысл хотел вложить в это предложение автор, на чём он делал упор  -- ни Вы, ни я не знаем...

Answer (score 0):

Не надо ставить запятую, если нет особой интонации присоединения. Здесь можно два варианта допустить: часть предложения *предположительно за счет уменьшения образования гидрокарбонат-ионов* рассматривать как присоединительную конструкцию и тогда ставить запятую или же рассматривать как единое целое (без интонации присоединения), тогда не надо запятой.